# Creating new layer that shows income demographics for US by zip code in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am trying to create a map to plot specific points on the US and compare information such as income, race, religion, and so on.

I am using the shapefile Zip Code Tabulation Area from Census.gov and have pinpointed my info to the specific locations.

Is there a way I can create a new layer that shows the income demographics for the US by zip code?

Answer (score 2):

(UPDATED - original answer wasn't what they were asking for)

Per your comment below, you are asking where you can find/download data about income by zipcode.

It's here: 
https://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats-Individual-Income-Tax-Statistics-2013-ZIP-Code-Data-(SOI)

Comment: Hi thanks for your advice, but I already have the basic gist of symbolizing layers. Im just wondering how to add a layer or shapefile to my map that represents the average income levels in the US by zipcode. I cant seem to find any.

Comment: Okay, so that's a different question. Go to this IRS link to get income by zipcode: https://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats-Individual-Income-Tax-Statistics-2013-ZIP-Code-Data-(SOI)

Comment: The IRS site you gave me has a lot of information. Is there one big pdf file that has one average income per zip code?

Comment: @AG123, there is a link right there on the site that has everything you need. Download this one: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-soi/zipcode2013.zip  -- Unzip that, and open "13zpallagi.csv" in ArcMap. There is even a reference document "13zpdoc.doc" that tells you exactly what all the information means in that zip file.

Comment: Last question hopefully haha. How do i open the file in Arc Map?

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/adding-layers-to-a-map.htm

Comment: @AG123, it sounds like you need to take some basic ArcMap classes, because if you don't know how to add data to ArcMap, you are going to have a very difficult time figuring out how to use the Census data. Here is a good start for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekmyWkAP4eI

Comment: The file you gave me has many zip codes repeated with different information. I just need one median household income per zip code.

Comment: Open the file with "no agi" instead. The help document tells you which column has the data you need.

Comment: What does adjust gross income (A00100) exactly mean because it cant be income per household? Thanks for your help btw. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know that answer. You'll need to do some research :-)